# How to get difference in hours between two datetime in floating or decimal in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm facing issue while calculating difference between two dates in decimal.

```
Date1:- 2019-07-02 16:42:06
Date2:- 2019-07-02 15:53:01
```

Expected Result:- 0:49:05

```
select datetime_diff('2019-07-02 16:42:06','2019-07-02 15:53:01',Hour)
```

BigQuery Output:-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Expected Result:- 0:49:05

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
  SELECT FORMAT('%i%s', 
    DIV(DATETIME_DIFF(date1, date2, MINUTE), 60),
    FORMAT_TIME(':%M:%S', TIME(DATETIME_ADD(DATETIME(TIMESTAMP(DATE(1970, 1, 1))), INTERVAL DATETIME_DIFF(date1, date2, SECOND) SECOND)))
  ) AS diff
```

For DATETIME '2019-07-05 17:42:06' date1, DATETIME '2019-07-02 15:53:01' date2 it gives

```
diff     
73:49:05
```

For DATETIME '2019-07-02 17:42:06' date1, DATETIME '2019-07-02 15:53:01' date2 result is

```
diff     
1:49:05
```

For DATETIME '2019-07-02 16:42:06' date1, DATETIME '2019-07-02 15:53:01' date2 (as in your question) result is

```
diff     
0:49:05
```

If you know that the difference will be within 24 hours you can use simpler statement as below

```
FORMAT_TIME('%T', TIME(DATETIME_ADD(DATETIME(TIMESTAMP(DATE(1970, 1, 1))), INTERVAL DATETIME_DIFF(date1, date2, SECOND) SECOND)))
```

For last two examples result will be respectively `01:49:05` and `00:49:05`

Answer (score 3):

If you want a *decimal* value, then use a smaller unit and arithmetic:

```
select datetime_diff('2019-07-02 16:42:06', '2019-07-02 15:53:01', second) / (60 * 60.0) as decimal_hours
```

Your sample result is not a decimal value.

Comment: Actually i need either 0 or 0:49. Agreed expected output is not decimal,its time.Moreover this is just the sample and further calculations are applied on this output.